# Syntax error while defining class in C++

Tags: c++, class, syntax-error, declaration

I am trying to create this class in C++ but the compiler keeps giving me a syntax error at it's declaration. The global variables are necessary.

This is the error message

> include\SInterface.h(36) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier
>   'SInterfaceClass'

```
#ifndef __SINTHDR__
#define __SINTHDR__
#include "Global.h"

typedef unsigned int  uint;

typedef struct
{
    float d1;
    float d2;
    float d3;
    float d4;
    float para;
    float mode;
} DeflStruct;

// Simulation Inputs
// ====================================================================
    float SimAcc [3] = {0};
    float SimGyr [3] = {0};
    //
    // More Global floats being defined here
    //
    float SimOutPara    =  0 ;
    float SimOutMode    =  0 ;

class SInterfaceClass {  // line 36
private:
    float ITime;
    float IPrevTime;
    //
    // More floats being defined here
    //
    float Ic1_bf_psi_rate;
    float Ic1_bf_phi_rate;


public:
    SInterfaceClass();
    DeflStruct Output(
                    Vect3   Acc ,
                    Vect3   Gyr ,
                    double  Pre ,
                    Vect3   Vel ,
                    Vect3   Eul ,
                    Vect3   Inc ,
                    Vect3   Pos ,
                    double  Time);

};

#endif
```

Comment: Why are you using `typedef struct` instead of just `struct`?

Comment: Is anything important int `Global.h`?

Comment: This class is part of an interface that should join a program written in pure C to a Simulink/Matlab simulation model. I was working on that just before this and kind of did it automatically.

Comment: Global.h contains the declaration of the global variables that the C program uses.

Comment: If I remove the `#include "Global.h"`, I just get undeclared identifier errors starting with `Vect3 Acc ,`. There's probably something in `Global.h` that creates a conflict, perhaps an ill-advised macro definition.

Comment: @AarondeWindt: If `Global.h` isn't huge, edit your question to show it to us. If it is huge, try reducing it to the minimal example that exhibits the problem (it's likely you'll figure out the problem yourself while doing this).

Comment: So wait, you're compiling in C or C++? C has no classes.

Comment: Global.h also includes the declaration to some struct's and typedef's that the variables use.

Comment: The other program itself should be pure C since it has to go to a microcontroller. But to test it I'm creating this interface in C++. It's part of an simulink S-function.

Comment: Global.h uses `extern "C"` blocks? If so, are those blocks properly closed?

Comment: Post a *complete* snippet that reproduces this error. As written excluding `Global.h` happily passes the marked line without error and continues on until the `Vect3` members, where are of course not valid because there is no `Global.h`.

Comment: Try renaming the file to SInterface.hpp and check if that helps, then it should be considered c++ by default. If so you know it was the language-recognition somehow failing.

Answer (score 0):

I see two reasons. The first one that this error is the result of some inconsistence in header **"Global.h"**

The second one is that the compiler compiles your code as C code not as C++ code.

Comment: Global.h is fine as I know. I've already compiled it and tested it and I already checked if it's compiling C++ using the #ifdef __cplusplus